# wc_get_template_part in custom query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a problem with custom query for upsell products.
I'm trying to create popup on single-product.php page which pops when someone click add to cart button and shows upsells products.

I manage to create custom query which get upsell product in this popup but i've got a problem when  it comes to get product template.

Right now code looks like this:

```
function the_dramatist_return_post_id() {
    $product_id = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );
    $product = new WC_Product($product_id);
    $upsells = $product->get_upsells();
    
    if (!$upsells)
        return;

    $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'no_found_rows' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'post__in' => $upsells,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query
    );
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($args); // (2)
     if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : // (3)
        while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : 
                    $wc_query->the_post(); 
//                  $upsell_product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
//                  echo $upsell_product;
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Brak produktów' ); // (8) ?></p>
    <?php endif;
}
```

But no products are displayed.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Best regards, Kuba!

Comment: wc_get_product returns the product object. So you're starting off wrong. Remove $product = new WC_Product(

Comment: Why should i do it? This line allows me to get upsells products by  $upsells = $product->get_upsells(); . All problem start on while loop where i can't get temlape part, but i can easly get title, id and other product properties.